# UI textfield input into an array

Tags: swift

I am trying to store user input text into an array (wordArray) so I can output it as a UI label and place it randomly on my screen. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Any code you already tried would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try like this. if your Condition Satisfies . other wise Comment Your Code We Will help you

```
let myArray:[UILabel] = [label1,label2,label3,label4,...]
var index = 0
for text in wordArray {
myarray[index].text = text
index += 1
 }
```